# Jump to some specific line in the vi editor

Tags: command-line, vi

How can I jump the line in the vi editor? Once I open any file using the vi editor and I have such a line:

```
printf("jfdkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkjghjthrttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttujhrjghjrhjghrtjhgjhtrjhgjhjjrjwhjghjrhghrhgjhrjghjrhhhhhhhgjkrhgjrhjgrhg");
```

So what should I do if I want to directly go to the end of the line or jump the line? For now I have to travel the whole line. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the line by searching for some unique part of it with `/`

Press <kbd>esc</kbd> and type:

```
/printf
```

and the cursor will jump to the first instance of `printf`. press `n` to go to the next match until you reach the line you want. To move to the end in normal mode, type

```
$
```

To jump to the end and change to insert mode, type:

```
A
```

(<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

Answer (score 7):

You can also press the <kbd>end</kbd> key which will put the cursor to the end of the line.

To go to a specific line like line 44 press <kbd>esc</kbd> then

```
:44
```

Comment: Or in command mode just type 44zt to jump to line  and position the  line  on top of the screen. I use this a lot lately

Answer (score 2):

Here are some basic vim commands which will help you accomplish some of the basic tasks. Try this in normal mode not in insert mode.

**e** Move to the end of a word.

**w** Move forward to the beginning of a word.

**3w** Move forward three words.

**W** Move forward a WORD (any non-whitespace characters).

**b** Move backward to the beginning of a word.

**3b** Move backward three words.

**$** Move to the end of the line.

**0** Move to the beginning of the line.

If you are new to vim I recommend you to complete the vimtutor. From terminal type **vimtutor** . Finish it so that you will be confident in editng using vim.

Comment: helpful , upvoted